# Overlay widget partially outside the bounds of it's parent

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget

I'm trying to create a compound widget similiar to the following:

[image: My compound widget]

A Rectangle overlayed with a button that is partially outside the rectangle's bounds.

Here is the code corresponding to that image:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QResizeEvent


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.lbl = QLabel()
        self.lbl.setStyleSheet('background: #EE6622')
        self.lbl.setFixedSize(125, 150)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl)

        self.btn = QPushButton(parent=self)
        self.btn.setStyleSheet('background: #ABCDEF')
        self.btn.setFixedSize(25, 25)

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent) -> None:
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.update_btn_pos()

    def update_btn_pos(self):
        pos = (
            self.lbl.pos() +
            QPoint(
                self.lbl.rect().width() - int(self.btn.width() / 2),
                -int(self.btn.height() / 2))
        )
        self.btn.move(pos)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    a.exec()
```

My problem is that the widget's behaviour when resizing suggests that the button is not really *"part of"* that widget - it is cut-off as if it weren't there:

[image: Widget when resized]

I tried to overwrite the **sizeHint()**-method to include the button, but that only solves the problem on startup, I can still resize the window manually to cut the button off again.

What must be changed in order to make this work?

Comment: Note that if you want to center the button on the top right corner, you don't need to compute the position based on the sizes; try to change `update_btn_pos` to: `rect = self.btn.rect(); rect.moveCenter(self.lbl.geometry().topRight()); self.btn.move(rect.topLeft())` (each semicolon is for a new line). It could be slightly slower (but we're talking about differences in the order of *micro* seconds) but it's much more readable and "Qt-onic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have found a solution myself by adding the following to the **__init__** - method:

```
self.layout.setContentsMargins(
    0, 
    int(self.btn.height() / 2),
    int(self.btn.width() / 2), 
    0
)
```

By setting the **contentsMargin**, the size of the big rectangle doesn't change because it is fixed and the parent widget still covers the space under the button:

[image: Widget respecting the button's space]

I'm not sure if this is the **right way** to do it though ...

---

Alright, thanks to **@musicamante** this is the final code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QResizeEvent


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.lbl = QLabel()
        self.lbl.setStyleSheet('background: #EE6622')
        self.lbl.setFixedSize(125, 150)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl)

        self.btn = QPushButton(parent=self)
        self.btn.setStyleSheet('background: #ABCDEF')
        self.btn.setFixedSize(25, 25)

        # set contents margin of layout to half the button's size
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(
            *([int(self.btn.height() / 2), int(self.btn.width() / 2)]*2)
        )

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent) -> None:
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.update_btn_pos()

    def update_btn_pos(self):
        rect = self.btn.rect()
        rect.moveCenter(self.lbl.geometry().topRight())
        self.btn.move(rect.topLeft())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    a.exec()
```

Result:
[image: Widget with padding at all sides]

Comment: This *could* be a solution. It's not clear, though, if this is the expected result: shouldn't the orange label be centered?

Comment: Ideally it should ...
I could add the same space to the bottom and the left as well - that would center it again, but then there'd be too much empty space around.

Comment: If it has to be centered, it's pretty normal that there would be space around when shown at the minimum size, so I don't really understand what you're looking for. Do you expect to have the result shown in the image above when shown with minimum size, but "adapt" it (by aligning to the center) when there's more available space?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't think that through - if it's centered the space will be there anyway.
I just set the contentsMargin on all four sides and I'm good to go.

Answer (score 0):

On paint event widget paints itself and all of his children clipped to his bounds. You can try to set button parent to `MyWidget`'s parent, but you'll still have problem of button blocking part of some other widget or clipping on window's client area.

On the other hand there is no much difference between hovering button thats inside parent's widget and hovering button that sticks out, messing with other widgets.